# how to create an android softphone with android.media.audiorecord?

Tags: android

I need to create an android softphone using the native libraries like android.media.AudioRecord but I don't have any idea about how start it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Androids AudioRecord is not that difficult, all you need to do is initialize it, spawn a thread, then call startRecording() and then read the mic data from within the thread.

You'll soon find that the most difficult part of you Android softphone will be playback latency and find yourself going down the OpenSL ES route for audio playback.  Even with an OpenSL ES driver, you'll find that the playback latency dismal on devices that lack the low latency audio support.

There are a few really good open source softphones for Android, they'd be a good starting point for how to use AudioRecord and AudioTrack.

Comment: Could you show me a basic example, please?